# Convert byte array to Mat in JavaCV

Tags: scala, opencv, javacv

Like this:

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.Mat
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.{opencv_core, opencv_imgcodecs}

val jpegRawBytes: Array[Byte] = ???  // this is given, not a problem

val matRaw = new Mat(1, jpegRawBytes.length, opencv_core.CV_8UC1)
??? // mat.put(jpegRawBytes)
val matImg = opencv_imgcodecs.imdecode(matRaw, opencv_imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

How would I do the second `???` step, putting the `Array[Byte]` into the `Mat`?

---

Here is one, but it looks very inefficient, having to call `put` for each single byte:

```
val idxRaw  = matRaw.createIndexer[UByteRawIndexer]()
var i = 0
while (i < jpegRawBytes.length) {
  idxRaw.put(0, i, jpegRawBytes(i))
  i += 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static Mat toMat(BufferedImage bi) {
    OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage cv = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();
    Java2DFrameConverter jcv = new Java2DFrameConverter();
    return cv.convertToMat(jcv.convert(bi));
}

public static Mat toMat(byte[] bs) {
    return toMat(toBufferedImage(bs));
}

public static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(byte[] bs) {
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bs));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CEIUtils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```